# Но(,) поверьте:/, всë, что я делал, было не просто так!

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, двоеточие, запятые-или-двоеточие

Как расставить?

`Но поверьте: всë, что я делал, было не просто так!`

`Но, поверьте, всë, что я делал, было не просто так!`

Comment: Э-э... Максим, Вы выбрали метку "обращение". Извините, а *где* у нас тут обращение?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова А может, _поверьте_ — обращение?

Comment: *Поверьте* — обращение?!  **<Поверь(те); поверишь (ли); поверите (ли), *в зн. вводн. сл.*** Употр. с целью убедить собеседника в то, (*sic*) что говорится. *Поверь, я не со зла. Поверишь ли, кого я видел? Не поверите, но эксперимент проведён за два часа.* (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Извините уж, не знал. Что злиться-то? Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Я — злюсь? Бог с Вами. Удивляюсь. Поэтому и спросила. Ещё раз извините.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ну, выглядит как злость. Не сразу-с поймëшь-то, что таки это удивление.